# Unexpected token for ajax request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am using json with jquery's ajax. There are two options for results in this code:
one of them null result 
one of them is html result for example ...

When I used firefox this code result not enter `if(sdata!="")` or `sdata!=null`

If I try to return with json type it's return, but I don't return html token. It returns an exception

> unexcepted token `<`

How can I solve?

```
$.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("RefreshPage", "VeriAktarim")',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { key: id },
                        success: function (sdata) {
                            if (sdata != "") {
                                $("#" + change).closest("tr").replaceWith(sdata);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (req, status, error) {
                            alert(status + "error" + error);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Trying adding `dataType: "text"` in the `$.ajax` options.

Comment: Can you post your json response string

Comment: i am trying to return text but response returns undefined Json(new
            {
                Success = "basarisiz",
            }, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);